# One pixel gap below task bar on Windows

Tags: windows

For some reason there is a single-pixel gap between the bottom of my taskbar and the bottom of my screen. When I click below it it clicks straight through to the desktop, like the taskbar window is offset upwards by one pixel. Anyone know how to fix this?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoPIX.jpg)

Comment: Do you notice this gap when moving the taskbar to a different position (e.g. to the top of the screen or the right side)?

Comment: This might be a separator.

Comment: Is this somehow the "show desktop" button that has snuck under your taskbar instead of being at the far right ? Have you tried right clicking it ? Does it give you the option for a peek preview of your desktop on mouseover ?

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Personalization > Colors

Under "Show accent color on the following surfaces"

Uncheck "Start, taskbar, and action center"

Depending on your preference, you may also want to uncheck the "Title bars and window borders" option.

This is what was causing the issue for me. If you change the accent color and the 1px line does not change colors, it may be another issue.

-E